# Why a linear trasformation doesn't depend on the bases we choose

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Imagine we are given the following linear transformation:

$f(x,y) = (x+y, x)$

Imagine we choose a base, let's call it $B_{1}$ and we apply the function to some vector. Now imagine we choose another base, call it $B_{2}$ and we apply it to the same vector(with the coordinates given in base $B_{2}$) How can I assure the function will give me the same vector, I mean how can I assure the resultant vector is independent of the base I choose?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does $(x,y)$ mean in this context?

Comment: We have a base $B$ in $R^{2}$, so $(x,y)$ are the coordinates of the vector in the base.

Comment: So you have a linear map $V:\to V$ and relative to some basis $\mathbf{u,v}$  it is given by $f(x,y)=(x+y,x)$ in other words $f(x\mathbf{u}+y\mathbf{v})=(x+y)\mathbf{u}+y\mathbf{v}$. If you now change to another basis, then the expression for $f$ relative to the new base will be different to ensure the same result.

Answer (score 0):

A vector has $2$ characteristics: its length(modulus) and (when an axis is fixed) its inclination with an axis . These two properties are **related only with the vector** and nothing else. The bases you choose are just different measuring units.. (like **cm,m & km**).

Think it like this. First comes the vector then the measuring units you choose.. Not the other way round. The vector will always remain the same whichever axis(coordinate system) you choose to represent it with.. Only the value of the length and angles will change .. not the vector..

Comment: But the inclination with an axis changes when we change the axis.

Comment: This answer only seems to apply to scalar transformations of $\mathbb{R}^2$. It's not clear the OP intended to limit the question to this case.

Comment: @Micapps Not necessarily.. In $\mathbb{R}^3$ you just need more than 1 angle. In higher dimensions **just** the number of angles is increased(talking abour polar coordinates..) . So the number of measurements are increased..Nothing else changes.. vectors remain the same..

Answer (score 0):

The line "$f(x,y) = (x+y,x)$" defines a function $f : \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$.
You don't need  to know that $\Bbb R^2$ is a vector space and you don't need to look at a basis, to know that $f(4,7) = (11,4)$.